# how to make my website that is on Amazon EC2 load faster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm currently developing CRM with a t2.micro EC2 instance and it works very slow but the average usage of the instance is stable under 50% if I use auto-scaling it will help the speed, or maybe another tool in order for it to work faster?

Comment: Why are you using a t2.micro? This is a burstable instance type that will "slow down" after sustained usage. See: [Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)

Comment: Using autoscaling might help -but only if the problem is lack of ec2 capacity, if the issue is RDS for example then autoscaling might make it worse. Gather some data from your setup and update your question. Start with cloudwatch metrics for your EC2, RDS and EBS. You need to think about CPU, RAM, Disk IO & network IO. Also open Chrome's network tab then load your site and look at the waterfall graph. how long does the first request take, how long for all requests and how many requests are made in total?

Answer (score 0):

This is so big topic and there are a lot of answers and many of them will be correct.
Shortly the fastest web site in the world is the one that is very small and deployed geographically near you. 
I would recommend to start with https://www.webpagetest.org/ to see the list of issues to start your investigation path.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure t2.micro is the right instance size for each node. Each node must have enough capacity to sustain a reasonable demand, and this is all variable and depends on your own benchmarking.

If your CRM tier is stateless, meaning session store is out of the instance, Auto-Scaling will surely help you scale-out and allocate the right number of nodes.

But the key is to **find the right balance between vertical and horizontal scaling**.